# Get data from FireStore and display it as HTML

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, web-deployment

I have an `Android app` that creates a post as of `HTML` code
I'm trying to get this code on the website and display it as a website but my web experience is a bit mediocre and I couldn't find a solution to my problem
I tried for more than a week and I think that I have to learn programming sites from scratch to be able to solve the problem.

image from databases :

[image]

Here are some snippets I tried and it didn't work :

```
<script>
            var  config  = {
              apiKey: "AIzaSyBIlwe_P7Wq**********",
              authDomain: "fir-eivi-27********",
              databaseURL: "https://fir-eivi******",
              projectId: "s-eivi",
              storageBucket: "s-eivi.appspot.com",
              messagingSenderId: "358*****",
              appId: "1:358302572********"
            };

            firebase.initializeApp(config);
            var database = firebase.database();
              var starCountRef = database.ref('post/Tra0bUpkh90c2OSU7OQx/HTML');
                  starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
                    updateStarCount(postElement, snapshot.val());
                  });

                  // update the UI
                  function updateStarCount(el, val) {
                    el.innerHtml(`${val} post`);
                    consol.log(val);
                  }


</script>
```

Also, is this the correct way to receive text from the script :

```
<p id='starCountRef' class="p-2 row m-0"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot you show is from Cloud Firestore, but your code is using the API to access the Realtime Database. While both databases are part of Firebase, they are completely separate and the API for one doesn't work with the other.

So you'll want to start from the Firestore documentation, specifically this section on [using realtime listeners to get data and updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen). The equivalent to your database code would be something like this:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
db.collection("post").doc("Tra0bUpkh90c2OSU7OQx")
    .onSnapshot((doc) => {
        console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
        updateStarCount(postElement, doc.data().HTML;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have observed that you have incorrectly written the "innerHTML" syntax.

```js
function updateStarCount(el, val) {
  el.innerHTML = `${val} post`;
  consol.log(val);
}
```

innerHTML syntax is incorrect.
innerHTML is not a function you have to assign value to it.